# How to make python class objects dependent on another and delete the object when the parent is deleted?

Tags: python, class, dependencies

I have two python classes A and B.
I want class A to depend on class B.
Also when class A is deleted class B should be deleted as well. Any help regarding this matter is appreciated.

I have tried the implement this by the following code.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.newobj = B()
    def __del__(self):
        del self.newobj
        print('an object of class A was destroyed')

class B:
    def __init__(self):
         #do stuff
    def __del__(self):
        print('an object of class B was destroyed')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    
    obj1= A()
    obj2 = obj1.newobj
```

when the destructor is being called because of class A, the newobj is not deleted.
If i try to delete obj2 inside the class A destructor, it would throw off an error saying obj2 was referenced before assignment.

Comment: Does it suffice that if the only reference to the child is through the parent, that the child will be garbage collected soon after the parent is deconstructed?

Comment: FYI, `__del__` is not guaranteed to be called if the interpreter exits and there is still a reference to it somewhere

Comment: With normal references, it's impossible. However, you might have more luck with playing with weak references - https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html Just note that garbage collector might take time to collect the parent. But: if somehow gets around your method/property and gets a normal reference, the sub-object will still live.

Comment: BTW, after only copypasting your code obj1.newobj `__del__` **is** called when obj1 is deleted.

Comment: @matszwecja i want the obj2 to be deleted too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With normal references, it's impossible. Deletion of resources is done when we have zero references left - and you just made a reference in obj2 which you cannot access in a different scope (some people say python passes arguments "by assignment" - creates new reference to the object)

However, python provides weak references. Weak references do not count towards garbage collecting. https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html

Notes:

- garbage collector might still take time to collect the parent (in example below I force it to collect)
- if someone gets a hold of a normal reference, the sub-object will stay alive

```py
import weakref 

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__newobj = B()  # use double underscore in name to strongly suggest it shouldn't be used directly
    @property
    def newobj(self):
        return weakref.ref(self.__newobj)

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = "test"

obj1 = A()
weak_obj2 = obj1.newobj
```

We access the object itself by calling the reference. Do not store this call in another variable as that will be a normal reference then.*

```
print(weak_obj2)  # <weakref at memoryaddresshere; to 'B' at anotheraddress>
print(weak_obj2())
print(weak_obj2().test)
```

Let's test it by deleting obj1 and forcing garbage collection

```
del obj1
import gc
gc.collect()

print(weak_obj2)  # <weakref at memoryaddresshere; dead>
print(weak_obj2())  # None
```

---

And as I mentioned, don't store the call as it's a normal reference and will keep the sub-object alive.

```py
obj1 = A()
weak_obj2 = obj1.newobj
obj2 = weak_obj2()  # storing the call

del obj1
gc.collect()
print(weak_obj2)  # not dead

del obj2
gc.collect()
print(weak_obj2)  # dead
```